# send this as argument of function in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i rewrite this function as below:

```
    $('#TblInvoiceList td img.ImgDelete').live('click' , function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
```

Desired form:

```
$('#TblInvoiceList td img.ImgDelete').live('click' , function () {
    delete(this);        
});

delete: function(){
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
}
```

Comment: As a seperate comment I recommend agains `.live` where possible. Resorting to `.click` or `.delegate` would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the value of `this` in a function use `Function.call()`, i.e.:

```
delete.call(this);
```

The first parameter to the `call()` and `apply()` methods set the context (i.e. the value of `this`) of the called function.

Alternatively, if your listener *only* has to call `delete` then write your event listener thus:

```
$('#TblInvoiceList td img.ImgDelete').live('click' , delete);
```

since there's no need for a new closure just to invoke `delete`.

Comment: But if i want to call the delete function from view.js then how it should look like: this is the call from view: $('#TblInvoiceList td img.ImgDelete').live('click', function () { _this.model.deleteRow(this);}

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#TblInvoiceList td img.ImgDelete').live('click' , delete);

var delete = function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
}
```

Just pass in the function directly so that `this` is scoped properly.

Comment: Thanks it helps. But if i want to call the delete function from view.js then how it should look like:  this is the call from view: $('#TblInvoiceList td img.ImgDelete').live('click', function () {            
            _this.model.delete(this);}